# Why VBScript SendKeys does not work for key combination?

Tags: vbscript, keyboard

As it is said on [social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx) to send key combinations we should use commands like:

```
object.SendKeys "^C"   ' for Ctrl-C
```

But it does not work. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys works fine with lowercase letters in commands, e.g.:

```
object.SendKeys "^c"   ' for Ctrl-C
```